# How to sort by nested object values in a dynamic function

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, object

I have an array of objects that looks like this :

```
let obj = [
    { name: 'John',
      company: {name: 'Wilsons'}
    },
    { name: 'Jim',
      company: {name: 'Allisons'}
    },
    { name: 'George',
      company: {name: 'Filberts'}
    },
]
```

Ideally, I can sort this dynamically, by running

```
const sortMe = val => {
obj.sort((a, b) => a[val] > b.[val])
}

sortMe(company.name) =

[
    { name: 'Jim',
      company: {name: 'Allisons'}
    },

    { name: 'George',
      company: {name: 'Filberts'}
    },
    { name: 'John',
      company: {name: 'Wilsons'}
    },
]

sortMe(name)
=> sorted by name...
```

But it won't work. I also tried splitting the value with a conditional

```
        if (val.includes('.')) {
            let categories = val.split('.')
[...obj].sort((a, b) => {
                if (a[categories[0]][categories[1]] < 
                    b[categories[0]][categories[1]]) {
                  return -1;
                } if (a[categories[0]][categories[1]] >
                      b[categories[0]][categories[1]]) {
                  return 1;
                }
                return 0;
              })
        }
```

which would essentially give me company and name as separate values and I could target it that way. But it did not work.

Comment: Did you try out some of the answers? Consider giving some feedback greetings!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `obj [company.name]` is not going to return what you are looking for.  That snippet means: take the `company` value in the current scope, find its `name` property, and then find the property with that name in `obj` and return its value.  This fails because there is no `company` object in scope there.  But changing to a string doesn't work either:  `obj ['company.name']` is not looking for the `name` property in the `company` property of `obj`.  Instead, it's looking for the property with name `company.name` in `obj`, which doesn't exist.  This does work:  `obj['company']['name']`, which is equivalent to `obj.company.name`, but it doesn't allow you to specify the sort key with a string.

We can write a simple helper function that gets the value at a dot-separated path.  Then, using that, we can write your sorter:

```js
const get = (path) => (obj) =>
  path .split ('.') .reduce ((o, p) => (o || {}) [p], obj)

const sortMe = (path) => (xs) => 
  xs .sort ((a, b, aa = get (path) (a), bb = get (path) (b)) => 
    aa < bb ? -1 : aa > bb ? 1 : 0
  )

const obj = [{name: 'John', company: {name: 'Wilsons'}}, {name: 'Jim', company: {name: 'Allisons'}}, {name: 'George', company: {name: 'Filberts'}}]

console .log (sortMe ('company.name') (obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

But I prefer a slightly different API with the same basic implementation.  I think this reads better:

```js
obj .sort (by ('company.name'))
```

And we can implement that version like this:

```js
const get = (path) => (obj) =>
  path .split ('.') .reduce ((o, p) => (o || {}) [p], obj)

const by = (path) => (a, b, aa = get (path) (a), bb = get (path) (b)) => 
  aa < bb ? -1 : aa > bb ? 1 : 0  

const obj = [{name: 'John', company: {name: 'Wilsons'}}, {name: 'Jim', company: {name: 'Allisons'}}, {name: 'George', company: {name: 'Filberts'}}]

console .log (obj .sort (by ('company.name')))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by object property values by using `sort()` and `localeCompare()`.

> The localeCompare() method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before, or after, or is the same as the given string in sort order.

```js
const objects = [{
    name: 'John',
    company: {
      name: 'Wilsons'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'Jim',
    company: {
      name: 'Allisons'
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'George',
    company: {
      name: 'Filberts'
    }
  },
];

// sort
const sorted = objects.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.company.name.localeCompare(b.company.name);
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the nested property as an array

```
let objs = [
    { name: 'John',
      company: {name: 'Wilsons'}
    },
    { name: 'Jim',
      company: {name: 'Allisons'}
    },
    { name: 'George',
      company: {name: 'Filberts'}
    },
]

const getValue = (obj, propChain) => {
    let value = obj;
    propChain.forEach(prop => {
        value = value[prop];
    });

    return value;
}

const comparator = (propChain) => {

   return (a, b) => {
       return getValue(a, propChain) > getValue(b, propChain) ? 1 : -1;
   }

}

const sortMe = (arr, propChain) => {
  return arr.sort(comparator(propChain));
};

console.log(sortMe(objs, ['company', 'name']));
```